# Click event on button type input is not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am designing webpage using jquery and php. My page has side menu, and clicking one of the option it send a request to server to read some information from file and it will create a form out of it, with submit and other button edit(in case anybody wants to change the information in that form) and send this html back to client. I am able to do this successfully. But when I click on the edit button it actually not calling the click handler I registered for the all the buttons.

```
$('button').click(function(){
  alert("click event");
 });
```

I included this in the

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
```

But because all the jquery/js code in ready() and it gets executed at the page load time, its not able to find these buttons in form because its something which i get from server after loading and replacing it to existing 'div' and hence its not able to invoke the event handler. If I define click handler for the parent div of this form, it receives the click event if I click 'edit' button because that 'div' was present when initial page got loaded. I might not be doing it correctly, may be getting the whole form from server is not a good idea, if you have to do some operation on the form at client side. But is it doable? if yes then whats the possible way out?. Thanks!

Comment: there is no 'button' element, only input with type button, ie you need `$(":button")`

Comment: @scibuff [I would doubt that](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5).

Comment: @scibuff - of course there is a button element. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5

Comment: just to clarify, both buttons (submit and edit) are basically input of type='button'.

Comment: @AnilVishnoi: If your buttons are in fact `input` elements then you would need to change your jQuery selector.  Currently what you have in the question will only match `button` elements (and all of them at that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your event isn't firing because you define it prior to the element existing on the page. Using the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method should fix this. Something along the lines of:

```
$('body').on('click','button', function(){
    alert("click event");
});
```

should work.

Comment: The only solution, which will work, of course not after everyone updates their answers. :)

Comment: It seems to be working. But is there any way I can figure out the id/value of the button got clicked?

Comment: SO won't let me insert just a single keystroke but the snippet needs a closing paren.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly you adding the buttons dynamic to the form. You should try to use `jQuery.on()` insteed, see http://api.jquery.com/on/

And in your example this might work for you

```
  $("body").on("button","click", function(event){
     alert("Hello world");
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (jQuery 1.7 and up). Previously was [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (1.4.2+), before that [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)...

```
$('*your_form*').on('click', 'button', function(){
  alert("click event");
});
```

Comment: If the button is being added by an AJAX call, this won't work.

Comment: @j08691 True. I've adjusted to have his existing form as the matching DOM element and delegate to the Ajax added `button`'s inside

Answer (score 1):

You may simply need to use this instead:

```
$(document).on('click','button',function(){
    alert("click event");
});
```

(jQuery 1.7 or higher)

Answer (score 0):

you have to call using button id

```
$('#buttonid').click(function(){
  alert("click event");
 });
```

or button class

```
  $('.buttonclassname').click(function(){
      alert("click event");
     });
```

Comment: Why would you have to do that?

Comment: just posted what i know  . i cant post what you know :-)

Comment: @zod: What is it that you know?  jQuery selectors can operate on _many_ different factors, not just ids and classes.  Why would you believe otherwise?

Comment: i already tried this. I added this code in ready(), but because at the loading time these buttons ( and ids) doesn't exist to its not registering any handler for it. And I think thats why its not working.

Comment: @zod: Element selectors have always been part of jQuery.  Take a look at a blog post by John Resig from 2005: http://ejohn.org/blog/selectors-in-javascript/